# Ubuntu booting stuck: Started Gnome Display Manager- Started Hold until boot process finishes up

Tags: boot, 18.04, gnome

My screen is stuck on boot screen only. And it keeps on showing the following screen with following messages:

[image: Screen Stucked image 1]

[image: Screen Stucked image 2]

I restarted my system like a million times, but I am still stuck on this screen only. I remember before this problem happened, I was using my system and it was showing me some memory/storage warning pop up with examine and ignore buttons on it. So I ignored it, but later I went on to free some space from my home directory and I deleted few unrequired files, projects and applications. After that I restarted my system because I was not able to create an android TV emulator on my system, and since then, this is happening.

P.S. I don't exactly remember my Ubuntu version, but I think it is 18.04.

Comment: any detail about the graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like 30 minutes ago. This has to do with the GPU (Nvidia in my case) and Gnome. Assuming you installed the proprietary drivers like I did, in order to solve that bug you should, from that screen:

- get into a terminal pressing `ctrl+alt+F2`
- purge-delete the Nvidia drivers with `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-*`
- and finally `reboot`

the above process is what solved my issue and I trust will solve yours too. The same would probably apply for an AMD Radeon GPU